Can an enum be an array type?
I often have something like ..
enum DotNetType: String, CaseIterable {
    case guid = "Guid"
    case int = "Int32"
    case float = "Single"
    case dateTime = "DateTime"
    case string = "String"
    
    init?(_ s: String) {
        for v in DotNetType.allCases {
            if v.rawValue == s {
                self = v
                return
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

however, often,
    case guid = "Guid" // oh no, turns out may be "uuid", "id" or "specialId"

Obviously you can solve this by just having a switch, but it occurred to me it would be elegant if
enum DotNetType: [String], CaseIterable {
    case guid = ["Guid","uuid","id"]
    case int = ["Int32", "int", "Int", "integer"]
    case float = ["Single", "Float", "decimal"]
    case dateTime = ["DateTime", "ts", "timestamp"]
    case string = "String"

Unfortunately when I try this, the errors are far beyond my understanding of the guts of enum so I cannot make it work.
Is there a way to have the type of an enum, an array?
I can see many cases (other than just parsing string tags) where it would be handy to have an enum as an array.

Just to be clear, you ultimately want DotNetType("Guid") == DotNetType("uuid") == DotNetType("id") == DotNetType.guid? Do you care about what the rawValues of the enum cases are? Do you want rawValue to actually return an array, or you don't care as long as DotNetType.init behaves in the aforementioned way?

Quite!  Q1 - correct!  Q2 & Q3.A - as mentioned in the final sentence in the question, it would be very cute/advantageous (in many situations unrelated to literally parsing from string to the enum) if the rawValue was literally an array!  I guess the heart of the question is "Can an enum be an array type?" However  failing that, and it's always good to know if something is decisively not possible, , yes, Q3.B "behaves in the aforementioned way" would be cool. As I mention if you just try it, it almost seems to work but I'm not smart enough to pick apart the chain of requirements.

Sounds like an answer to me!  Good enough!  TY  Anyway it sounds like, simply, you CAN NOT have an array as an enum type?  What anyway is the spec?  It has to be a primitive or?? (Could one just box an array??)

Jesu!   Don't kill yourself over it dude!!  You're talking builder magic or something else ?

I'm talking about macros, not result builders.

I just realised that since you seem to have never touched macros before, the macro in my answer would totally fly over your head. So, in addition to the link in the previous comment, here's another that might help.

You know what we've mentioned macros before. I am a macro addict and missed them from objc!  You mentioned recently on this site that macros are now in Swift - that was completely news to me and, as I mentioned at the time, I've been trying to find an hour to get in to this apparent macro miracle!!! Here then is the perfect opportunity ..

Anyone have an idea for a better way to phrase the title? My initial thoughts were "have an enum value be an array? Psht, why does this have that bounty?" Before realizing you are actually asking for multi-raw-value enums, but I can't come up with something catchy for that

And this 10-year old question might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706832/can-swift-enums-have-multiple-raw-values

Cheers @Layman , no offense but it's an excellent question title. (i) enums have a type (ii) the type of an enum is often String, Int etc. (iii) the question, can the type be an array

@Layman I appreciate the link to that other question!  (The title of that question is bad, though! ;) )  It's fascinating how the language has changed so much.

PS "why does this have that bounty"  FYI I always add bounties (I'm not 7 yrs old, so having Disney points is embarrasing professionally; I try to get rid of them :) )  Also, NB/FWIW bounties have a stated reason, and it's given in bold text.

If you just want to associate multiple strings to each case of an enum, and have an initialiser that can return the correct case according to those strings, you can write a macro for that.
One macro for generating the initialiser, and another for annotating each case. The usage would look like this:
@RawNamesEnum
enum DotNetType {
    @RawNames("Guid", "uuid", "id")
    case guid
    @RawNames("Int32", "int", "Int", "integer")
    case int
    @RawNames("Single", "float", "decimal")
    case float
}

print(DotNetType("id"))

Here's the implementation:
// declarations:
@attached(member, names: named(init))
public macro RawNamesEnum() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "RawNamesEnum")
@attached(peer)
public macro RawNames(_ names: String...) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "RawNames")

// implementation:

// this is kind of dirty, but is very convenient for throwing compile time errors
extension String: @retroactive Error {}

enum RawNamesEnum: MemberMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let enumDecl = declaration.as(EnumDeclSyntax.self) else {
            throw "RawNamesEnum must be attached to an enum!"
        }
        var allNames: Set<String> = []
        var namesByCase: [String: Set<String>] = [:]
        let caseDecls = enumDecl.memberBlock.members.compactMap { $0.decl.as(EnumCaseDeclSyntax.self) }
        for caseDecl in caseDecls {
            let names = try getNames(fromCase: caseDecl)
            if !allNames.intersection(names).isEmpty {
                throw "Cannot contain duplicate names!"
            }
            allNames.formUnion(names)
            namesByCase[caseDecl.elements.first!.name.text] = names
        }
        
        let initDecl = InitializerDeclSyntax(optionalMark: "?", signature: .init(parameterClause: .init {
            "_ name: String"
        })) {
            
            for (caseName, rawNames) in namesByCase {
                let arrayLiteral = ArrayExprSyntax(expressions: rawNames.map { ExprSyntax(StringLiteralExprSyntax(content: $0)) })
                """
                if \(arrayLiteral).contains(name) {
                    self = .\(raw: caseName)
                    return
                }
                """
            }
            "return nil"
        }
        return [DeclSyntax(initDecl)]
    }
    
    static func getNames(fromCase caseDecl: EnumCaseDeclSyntax) throws -> Set<String> {
        var names: Set<String> = []
        for case let .attribute(attrSyntax) in caseDecl.attributes {
            guard attrSyntax.attributeName.as(IdentifierTypeSyntax.self)?.name.text == "RawNames",
                case let .argumentList(argList) = attrSyntax.arguments else { continue }
            for name in argList.compactMap({ $0.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue }) {
                if !names.insert(name).inserted {
                    throw "Cannot contain duplicate names!"
                }
            }
        }
        if names.isEmpty {
            names = [caseDecl.elements.first!.name.text]
        }
        return names
    }
}

enum RawNames: PeerMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let caseDecl = declaration.as(EnumCaseDeclSyntax.self) else {
            throw "RawNames can only be applied to enum cases"
        }
        guard caseDecl.elements.count == 1 else {
            throw "RawNames can only be applied to a single enum case declaration"
        }
        guard let firstCase = caseDecl.elements.first, firstCase.parameterClause == nil else {
            throw "RawNames cannot be applied to cases with associated values"
        }
        guard case let .argumentList(argList) = node.arguments,
              argList.allSatisfy({
                  $0.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue != nil
              }) else {
            throw "Names must all be string literals"
        }
        return []
    }
}

@main
struct MyMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        RawNamesEnum.self,
        RawNames.self
    ]
}


The raw value type of an enum cannot be an array. From the documentation,

The type of these values is specified in the raw-value type and must represent an integer, floating-point number, string, or single character. In particular, the raw-value type must conform to the Equatable protocol and one of the following protocols: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral for integer literals, ExpressibleByFloatLiteral for floating-point literals, ExpressibleByStringLiteral for string literals that contain any number of characters, and ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral or ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral for string literals that contain only a single character.

You can still manually conform to RawRepresentable and set the RawValue type to an array type. I'm not sure why you want to do this though...
enum Foo: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = [String]
    
    init?(rawValue: [String]) {
        // you need to write this by hand...
    }
    
    var rawValue: [String] {
        // you need to write this by hand...
    }
}

Technically, you can extend the @RawNamesEnum macro to also be an ExtensionMacro that generates a RawRepresentable conformance like the above, but I don't find that particularly useful.
