# How to get enum case name in Swift from within CustomStringConvertible implementation?

Tags: swift

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum IntteruptCause: UInt8 {
    case userDisplayDisengage = 0
    case userSteeringWheelDisengage = 1
    case positionDropout = 2
}
```

Currently the output from `print()` will give me the case name.

I would like to implment `CustomStringConvertible` and have it produce both the case name and the rawValue, e.g. the string `User_Steering_Wheel_Disengage (1)`.

When I implement `var description: String` I have easy access to `rawValue` but I cannot seem to find out how to get the enum case name. Normally I would do `String(describing: value)` but that would create an infinite recursion if used in `description` implementation.

Is it possible to get the enum case name from within the `description` implementation?

Comment: I think hardcoding them is the best way there is at the moment...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variables, including enum cases.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24113126.