# Printing description of system enum value only prints the enum name

Tags: ios, swift, enums

To get a string description of the enum value, I can usually just print it out as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31893968/14351818).

```
enum CustomEnum {
    case normal
    case special
}
let customEnum = CustomEnum.normal
print("Custom enum is: \(customEnum)")
```

*Result:* <kbd>[image]</kbd>

But, this doesn't work for system enums, for example [`UIView.ContentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode). It just prints out the name of the enum itself.

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let contentMode = imageView.contentMode
print("ContentMode is: \(contentMode)")
```

*Result:* <kbd>[image]</kbd>

I tried making a `String` explicitly like this:

```
let description = String(describing: contentMode)
print("Description is: \(description)")
```

Which doesn't have any effect: <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is it only possible to print the value by switching over all the possible values?

```
switch contentMode {
case .scaleToFill:
    print("mode is scaleToFill")
case .scaleAspectFit:
    print("mode is scaleAspectFit")
case .scaleAspectFill:
    print("mode is scaleAspectFill")
case .redraw:
    print("mode is redraw")
case .center:
    print("mode is center")
case .top:
    print("mode is top")
case .bottom:
    print("mode is bottom")
case .left:
    print("mode is left")
case .right:
    print("mode is right")
case .topLeft:
    print("mode is topLeft")
case .topRight:
    print("mode is topRight")
case .bottomLeft:
    print("mode is bottomLeft")
case .bottomRight:
    print("mode is bottomRight")
@unknown default:
    print("default")
}
```

This finally gives me the result I want: <kbd>[image]</kbd>

But this is really tedious, and I don't want to do this for every system enum if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can add extension on system enum and define description computed property, for exmple

Comment: LLVM strips this metadata (the case labels) so they aren‘t available at runtime. Reflection or other runtime magic won‘t work here. You‘ll have to provide a custom implementation for `CustomStringConvertable` switching over the cases and return their labels manually :(

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the implementation of the Content Mode, you will notice that it is a Int Enum. This way, you always gets it index instead of a proper description:

[image: Swift UIImageView ContentMode implementation]

But this is weird, because you still should be able to get the enum name, and if you want the number, you call *.rawValue*. Instead, we receive the rawValue as default. Probably we get a computed variable instead of the proper variable.

The work around I propose is the same as you did, but as an extension of the original enum, creating a function that does the work for you, maintaining the abstraction:

[image: ContentMode Enum extension]

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense! But it's not much of an improvement in terms of how much code you need to write...